# Difference Between OWL-LIST and RDF-LIST

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, protege

I cannot understand the difference between OWL-LIST and RDF-LIST. Secondly why OWL-DL do not support RDF-LIST due to OWL serialisation why? and how i can create OWL-LIST in OWL-DL

Comment: OWL-LIST and RDF-LIST? I have never heard of these names. In RDF and OWL there are containers (`rdf:Bag`, `rdf:Seq`, `rdf:Alt`) and collections (`rdf:List`). Can you give some examples of what, exactly, you are after?

Comment: Basically i am trying to model network firewall rules through an OWL-DL ontology, and i am trying to model the order of these rules to reason about their logical consequences. following is an [link](http://code.google.com/p/collections-ontology/wiki/OWLandOrdering) stating "OWL have no support for ordering, but the natural constructs from the underlying RDF vocabulary (rdf:List and rdf:nil) are unavailable in OWL-DL"

Comment: Can you give an example of such a rule, how you currently model it in OWL, and what exactly you are after in terms of 'ordering' them?

Comment: To clarify: the reason I ask for examples is that I think that for the problem you are trying to solve, you don't really need a list or collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I don't think that there is any standard thing called OWL-LIST.  There is a [CO-ODE List Ontology](http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/lists/2008/09/11/) that might be of interest to you if you need to represent lists in OWL:

> **Description**
>
> A set of entities used to describe the OWL list pattern. (see http://owl-workshop.man.ac.uk/acceptedLong/submission_12.pdf)

Also have a look at these that talk about tht ontology, [Sequences in OWL](http://protege.stanford.edu/conference/2006/submissions/slides/7.1_Drummond.pdf).  They touch upon the reason why the RDF list vocabulary (`rdf:List`, `rdf:first`, and `rdf:rest`) can't be used in OWL:  since RDF lists are used in the serialization of OWL, situations would arise where it would be unclear whether the triples were appearing as part of the data, or as part of the OWL encoding.

This [answer by Michael Schneider on answers.semanticweb.com](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/11286/owlxml-vs-rdfxml-serialization/11325) also explains the issue:

> If outside OWL 2 DL, there are many dangers to not safely get from RDF to the native OWL 2 syntax. One example is when RDF lists are used as normal entities instead of argument lists for OWL constructs, e.g., if used for something like ":me :traveledCountries (Argentina Belarus China)". There is simply no translation rule for constructs like this in the reverse RDF mapping.