# Can we use rdf:List in OWL 2 DL?

Tags: list, mapping, owl, semantic-web, rdfs

I'm reading a lot of solutions about describe list in OWL 2 DL and most of those ones propose to remake a structure similar to the which one that rdf defines: [W3C RDF Collection](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_collectionvocab)

Someone says that using rdf:List an OWL 2 DL ontology becomes an OWL FULL ontology. [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681662/difference-between-owl-list-and-rdf-list/17353894#17353894) explain that there is simply no translation rule for constructs like this in the reverse RDF mapping.

Now the problem: implement a structure similar to a rdf:List is quite simple but SPARQL 1.1 not support this custom structure as he does with a rdf:List, where is able to automatically generate rdf:first and rdf:rest entities etc. But is this problem overcome today? Because reading [this page](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/#Mapping_from_RDF_Graphs_to_the_Structural_Specification) seems so.

If I have misunderstood what the W3C page explains, can you suggest me a definitive solution about this problem.

Comment: SPARQL support for RDF lists is [limited](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#collections). Unfortunately, I can not understand what do you mean by automatically generated `rdf:first` and `rdf:last` entities. In SPARQL, you can work with list-like structures using property paths, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17530689/7879193).

Comment: OWL language (neither full or dl) does not support custom rdf:List. The content of the page provided by you is about mapping axiom view to the rdf representation, all rdf:List's from that page are parts of axioms. However if you are looking for a way to work with OWL and custom rdf:List together there is a software solution - [ONT-API](https://github.com/avicomp/ont-api), which is (java-)OWL-API based on Apache Jena, so you can work with OWL and pure Graph at the same. The Graph may content anything allowed by RDF, includign custom (i.e. non-axiomatic) rdf:List's also

Comment: @StanislavKralin I mean that if i use rdf:List in a INSERT with SPARQL, like this "[] :hasMembers (<m1> <m2> <m3>)" then SPARQL creates relations between members using rdf:first and rdf:rest properties. But in the case of a custom implemented list in my own ontology SPARQL don't recognize this as a list and don't provide any "automatic" way to create the list.